# Allowing kendo grid server filtering API call only on pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Angular Kendo grid with server filtering. On entering the first character kendo is firing the API call ( grid filtering is in row mode ). I would like to know is there a way to restrict API calls till user enters 3 characters or on pressing enter key.

My grid configuration is like below :

```
 vm.grid.setOptions({
  groupable: true,
  sortable: true,
  resizable: true,
  scrollable: true,
  reorderable: true,
  columns: gridColumns,
  excel: {
      allPages: true
  },
  page:2,
  pageable: {
    pageSizes: [10, 20, 50]
  },
  dataSource : {
    page:1,
    transport:{
      read: {
        url: pageurl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"                        
      },
      parameterMap: function (options) {
        reqObject.FilterData = {};
        //omitted for brevity  
        var request=JSON.stringify(reqObject);
        return request;
      }
    },
    schema: {
      data: dataField,
      total: totalCount          
    },        
    filter:{
      filters:[]
    },
    autoBind: false,
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true
  },
  filterable: {
    mode: "row"
  },
   columnMenu: {
    columns: false
  }     

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to trigger when at least 3 characters have been entered, you can specify a minLength at the column level.

I'd also suggest adding a delay so that if they keep typing, it will wait until they pause long enough to run the filter.

```
columns: [{
   field: "Name",
   title: "Name",
   filterable: {
       cell: {
           delay: 1000,
           minLength: 3
       }
   }
}
```